# openpyxl can't open xlxs file

Tags: python, excel

Trying to use python to open an excel file for the first time using openpyxl. I know the file is there and it opens fine in excel itself. I list the directory from the python script and it shows the file is there as well. But when I try and open it with openpyxl it returns an error saying it doesn't support the xlxs file format, only to tell in the list of supported formats xlxs is supported.
Totally confused. For such a simple thing am I doing something very wrong?

Here's the code:

```
def run():

sourceMiles = input("Enter mileage source file:" )
print("source=",sourceMiles)

arr = os.listdir()
print(arr)
#open the workbook to the first sheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(sourceMiles)
# Read the active sheet:
sheet = wb.active

print("c,4=", sheet["C4"].value)
```

and here's the console output:

```
    Enter mileage source file:mileageTable.xlxs
source= mileageTable.xlxs
['anonymizer', 'firstProject.qgz', 'generateBurndownReport.py', 'KPIs', 'landLayer.gpkg', 'mileageTable.xlsx', 'MIS 3140 Final Project SQL Code.docx', 'outputs', 'routing app', 'UDBX_Requirements_Ushr_HD_Map_Database_Exchange_Format_Specification.pdf', 'ushr_navigation.zip', '~$mileageTable.xlsx']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cpeddie\Documents\projects\generateBurndownReport.py", line 199, in <module>
    run()
  File "c:\Users\cpeddie\Documents\projects\generateBurndownReport.py", line 93, in run
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(sourceMiles)
  File "C:\Users\cpeddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\cpeddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\cpeddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 94, in _validate_archive
    raise InvalidFileException(msg)
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .xlxs file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Likely typo. `xlxs` ≠ `xlsx`.

Comment: Duh! Don't know how many times I tried that and looked at the error message and never noticed the spelling. :( Thanks!